# Magento 2.3.1 install setup stuck at 0%

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-1.7

While installing magento 2 (magento 2.3.1) it got stuck at 0%

```
    Starting Magento installation: File permissions check...

    Enabling Maintenance Mode...

    Installing deployment configuration...

    Installing database schema:
```

didn't load further.

config I use

```
    php_value memory_limit 2G
    php_value max_execution_time 36000
    php_value upload_max_filesize 512M
    php_value post_max_size 512M
    php_value max_input_vars 5000
    php_value max_input_time -1
    php_value expose_php on
    php_value xdebug.max_nesting_level 500
    php_value realpath_cache_size 10M
    php_value realpath_cache_ttl 7200
```

Comment: Did you check if MySQL is running and db user credentials are valid?

Comment: Use @Tobi, I've checked the DB is running plus credentials are also valid and version is 5.7.30-ndb-7.6.14.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the logs under your

> webserver/magentoInstallation/var/log

They have more details about your error.

If you tried to install on a WAMP Webserver you will find them under

> WAMPFolder/www/yourmagentoinstallation/var/log

Comment: !! I can't find anything only I got is Magento application not installed.

Comment: /var/www/html/var/log# cat debug.log 
Error: Application is not installed yet.  [] []

cat update.log 
INFO: Magento is not installed. [] []

cat update.cron.log 
cat system.log 
Error: Application is not installed yet.  [] []

cat setup.cron.log 
Please check var/log/update.log for execution summary.

Comment: cat install.log 
<span class="text-info">Starting Magento installation:</span><br><span class="text-info">File permissions check</span><br><span class="hidden">[Progress: 1 / 833]</span><br><span class="text-info">Required extensions check...</span><br><span class="hidden">[Progress: 2 / 833]</span><br><span class="text-info">Enabling Maintenance Mode</span><br><span class="hidden">[Progress: 3 / 833]</span><br><span class="text-info">Installing deployment configuration</span><br><span class="hidden">[Progress: 4 / 833]</span><br><span class="text-info">Installing database schema:</span><br>

Comment: Enable apache mod_rewrite

Then run sudo service apache2 restart

Or is this problem coming from your server